# What am I going to lose if I use DOJO and not YUI

Tags: struts2

I am working on a Struts 2 application.  I see that Struts 2 uses DOJO for Ajax support and UI components (some are Tabbedpanel, tree etc).

I wanted to know what advantage am I going lose in YUI thats not available in DOJO if I proceed in this way.

Answer (score 0):

Using dojo you are **possibly** able to use tags to render an ajax tree, etc.  In practice I find myself never using these stock ajax tags.  I'm using YUI w/ Struts2 - and I've just made my own modifications to the tag freemarker libraries - which works well.  Dojo/Struts2 works great if all you want is ajax client side validation.

Answer (score 0):

Hair :).  Have you looked at the [YUI plugin](https://cwiki.apache.org/S2PLUGINS/yui-plugin.html) for struts2